# Swing + MigLayout, dynamic grow and shrinking of other components

Tags: java, swing, layout, miglayout

I'd like to achieve to have components divide the total space available, depending on whether they should shrink or grow. This should happen dynamically, meaning; I don't have any information regarding the amount of components added to the screen. Components should, depending on their properties, remain their height or grow:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|   +-----------------------+   |
|   |       don't grow      |   |
|   +-----------------------+   |
|                               |
|   +-----------------------+   |
|   |                       |   |
|   |       growy           |   |
|   |                       |   |
|   +-----------------------+   |
|                               |
|   +-----------------------+   |
|   |       don't grow      |   |
|   +-----------------------+   |
|                               |
|   +-----------------------+   |
|   |       don't grow      |   |
|   +-----------------------+   |
|                               |
|   +-----------------------+   |
|   |                       |   |
|   |       growy           |   |
|   |                       |   |
|   +-----------------------+   |   
|                               |
|   +-----------------------+   |
|   |       don't grow      |   |
|   +-----------------------+   |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I was able to create the following result:

[image: Almost there.. but not quite]

Provided is the following [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
public class SimpleMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MigLayout");

        JPanel panel =  new JPanel(new MigLayout("debug, flowy", "grow", "grow"));

        // 1st set of textfields
        panel.add(new JTextField(), "shrink, growx, top");
        panel.add(new JTextField(), "grow, top");
        panel.add(new JTextField(), "shrink, growx, top");

        // 2nd set of textfields
        panel.add(new JTextField(), "shrink, growx, top");
        panel.add(new JTextField(), "grow, top");
        panel.add(new JTextField(), "shrink, growx, top");

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } 

}
```

The 2nd and 5th text field grow as expected. The others remain their size as expected, although their container does not "shrink" and is being treated to divide its space with other components. The 2nd and 5th text field should take all the "extra" space.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing I might've found a solution that suits the requirements mentioned in my question.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MigLayout");

    JPanel panel =  new JPanel(new MigLayout(new LC().debug(1000).flowY().fillX()));

    // 1rd set of components
    panel.add(new JLabel("Titel"), new CC().grow());
    panel.add(new JTextArea(), new CC().grow().push()); // this component can use all the extra space

    // 2st set of components
    panel.add(new JLabel("Titel"), new CC().grow());
    panel.add(new JTextField(), new CC().grow());
    panel.add(new JLabel("Description"), new CC().grow());

    // 3nd set of components
    panel.add(new JLabel("progress"), new CC().grow());
    panel.add(new JProgressBar(), new CC().grow());
    panel.add(new JTextArea(), new CC().grow().push()); // this component can use all the extra space


    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Results in:

[image: Result]

As you might notice, 2 components on screen take all the extra space, whereas other components are left to their default size.